# Ranking based on two columns

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Finding the Rank of the Particular User from the Database by comparing three columns.

```
Name | Score | Attempts | Time
test |   2   |   4      |  2019-01-29 19:50:11
tes2 |   2   |   1      |  2019-01-29 20:14:11
```

So the Expected Output should be

```
Name | Score | Attempts | Time                  | Rank
tes2 |   2   |   1      |  2019-01-29 20:14:11  |  1
test |   2   |   4      |  2019-01-29 19:50:11  |  2
```

If I wanted to search Rank for User 'test' then I should get Rank 2 as my Answer.

I have done the part from which I can get the overall Rank, but I couldn't able to find Rank for Individual User.

This is code I have written for getting Overall Rank.

```
select t.*, @r := @r + 1 as `new_rank`
from  tbl t,
(select @r := 0) r
order by `Rank` asc, `Tasks` desc`
```

SQL Version that I'm Using is 10.1.9-MariaDB

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` or `rank()`, depending on how you want ties handled.  For instance:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by rank asc, task desc) as new_rank
from t;
```

If you are using older versions of MySQL (as your code snippet suggests), then you can use variables, but you probably need a subquery:

```
select t.*, (@r := @r + 1) as new_rank
from (select t.* from tbl t order by Rank asc, Tasks desc) t cross join
     (select @r := 0) r;
```

One method to get a particular row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@r := @r + 1) as new_rank
      from (select t.* from tbl t order by Rank asc, Tasks desc) t cross join
           (select @r := 0) r
     ) t
where t.name = ?;
```

Comment: Im using 10.1.9-MariaDB Version and both method which you stated is not working giving some errors.

Comment: @LaveshKarnani . . . Don't be shy.  What might those errors be?

Comment: When I'm using your first Code then under new_rank i'm getting red mark stating that "An Alias was previously found"

Comment: And for Second Code I'm getting CROSS as unrecognized keyword

Comment: @LaveshKarnani . . . `row_number()` is supported in MariaDB since 10.2.0 (your version is older).  MariaDB definitely supports `cross join`, but you can replace it with a comma as in your query.

Comment: How to use WHERE clause in CROSS JOIN so that I can get the rank of Particular 
User only.

Comment: One relatively simply method is just to use a subquery and put a `where` clause in the outer query.

Comment: Can you please update the code and say how to achieve that.

Comment: I'm trying with your Code but Table is not getting displayed in the ORDER of Score in DESC and Attempts in ASC. Check the Image [link](https://ibb.co/3F4fCrJ)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dense_rank](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dense_rank/), helps you to rank in numerical order.

```
*Syntax : 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
       [ PARTITION BY partition_expression ]
       [ ORDER BY order_list ]
    )* 

select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by rank asc, task desc) as new_rank
from t;
```

Comment: Mine version is older so it won't support.

Comment: Okay fine @LaveshKarnani